# Displaying data quickly in another view

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Below is a gif of Twitter's app, switching back and forth from the post feed to different profiles:

http://i.imgur.com/9uKadmx.gifv

There are, from my understanding, two ways to pass data to a view. The first is by passing it from the previous view (`putExtra()`) and the second being fetching the data from an external API after the view is switched to.

I noticed that in the Twitter app, profile data (like the user's description and # of followers/following) takes no time at all to load.

Does this mean Twitter passes the user data from the post feed (meaning that they request the user data for each post in the feed) rather than fetching the data from the API after the view is switch to?

In other words, are they using `putExtra()` to pass the data from the previous view or do you think they are requesting the data from their API after the view is switched?

**P.S.** This isn't specifically a question of how *Twitter* does it, but rather a question of how data should be passed in general, using the example of Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no, it doesn't mean anything.

Long answer:
They can (and likely do) use some kind of caching. For example, you can have a singleton object holding profiles in a `LruCache` with their IDs as keys. As the first activity loads the data from the API, it puts profiles into said cache. Then, when the user navigates to the second activity, the only thing that needs to be passed along explicitly is the profile ID. The second activity needs to query this profile from the cache and, because it is in the memory already, it is available instantly. So, the algorithm the second activity works may be something like this:

1. Get the id from intent extras.
2. Look up a profile for this id in the in-memory LRU cache.
3. If not found, do the same with the persistent cache (SQLite).
4. If still not found, load it from the server.

Comment: So you're saying that they probably request the user data when they request the post feed and then cache it?

Comment: Anyway they need some user data to display the feed but they can load more then is needed for the feed itself. As for Twitter, I just checked their API docs and they indeed return a complete user profile with each tweet.